# Error : Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'recordId' of type 'Id' in LWC imperative call to Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, apex-param, promises

I have a simple LWC component that shows Contacts of a selected Account, i am calling the Apex method imperatively from my JS code while passing the Account recordId.

Here is the Apex method signature :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Contact> getRelatedContacts(Id recordId)
```

And my JS code snippet for the imperative call :

```
import getRelatedContacts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountService.getRelatedContacts';
...
@api
get recordId() {
    return this._recordId;
}
set recordId(value) {
   this._recordId = value;
   this.setAttribute('recordId', value);
}
...
console.log('In getRelatedContacts : '+typeof(this._recordId)+' | '+this._recordId); => this returns string & the recordId on the client side
        getRelatedContacts({
            recordId: '$_recordId'
        })
            .then(result => {
                this.relatedContacts = result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error.body.message;
                console.log('Error : '+this.error);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.isLoading = false; 
           });;
```

But i am receiving this error message on the client side:

> Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'recordId' of type 'Id'

I tried to change the Apex method signature to the following, and both passing **'$_recordId'** or **'$recordId'** but with no luck :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Contact> getRelatedContacts(String recordId)
```

And i get the following print with a System.debug on the server side after changing the parameter type to String :

> DEBUG|boatId: $_recordId or DEBUG|boatId: $recordId

Which is strange because i am using the same syntax used [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-and-salesforce-data/use-apex-to-work-with-data)

I found this [document](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_lc_apex_param_validation.htm) talking about the error message, but nothing about the types **'Id'** and **'String'**.

Please tell what i am missing and the correct way to pass a recordId to call Apex imperatively.
Thank you.

Comment: Is `getRelatedContacts` inside a method? If not, it should be, and `$recordId` parameter is correct.

Comment: Yes it is inside an onclick handle method

Answer (score 1):

I have few queries on your use case.

1. Are you using your LWC component in a record context ?

   If yes : Then the recordId is automatically set, the attribute should have @api
   decorator. And your implementation should work, the syntax is correct

   If No  : Which means you are setting the value of the recordId, to be sent to your
   apex. In this case the standard attribute $recordId will not be set, since
   this is not a record context. Use the following syntax :

   ```
        getRelatedContacts({
        recordId: this.recordId
        })
   ```

Comment: Yes, i tried that already and it worked. So the syntax $recordId works only in a record context ? because there is no details about that in the documentation [link](developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex)

Comment: Yes, recordId will only get set sutomatically in a record context. Refer the following link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_record_context

Comment: I know that, i meant the syntax with the dollar sign '$parameter' not only for a recordId, it only works in a record context for an imperative Apex call ?

Answer (score 0):

Wires use '$recordId', imperative calls use this.recordId

```
getRelatedContacts({
    recordId: this.recordId
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use '$recordId' you need to mark apex method as cacheable=true

Apex:
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static getObjs(Id recordId){
return [SELECT Id FROM obj WHERE Id = :recordId];
}

js:

@wire(getObjs, {recordId : '$recordId'})
fetchResult({data, error}){
if({data}){
doSomething();
}else if({error}){
handleError();
}
}

Calling Apex imperatively:
@AuraEnabled
public static getObjs(Id recordId){
return [SELECT Id FROM obj WHERE Id = :recordId];
}

getObjs({recordId : this.recordId})
.then({data} => {
doSomething();
})
.catch({error} => {
handleError();
})